# how I can get a list of countries with respective currency and language from NSLocale?

Tags: ios, swift, nslocale

I would like to get a list of countries with it respective Language and currency.

First I created my class to store the information I need:

```
class Country: NSObject {

    var localeID:String?
    var name:String?
    var code:String?
    var currencyCode:String?
    var currencySymbol:String?
    var currencyName:String?
    var languageCode:String?
    var languageName:String?
}
```

Then I started the iteration over ISOCountryCodes with:

```
    let countriesISOCodes = NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes()
    for country in countriesISOCodes {
         // code here .....
    }
```

Then I tried to get the country name inside ***for loop*** with :

```
    let anyLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: country)
    country.name = anyLocale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, value : code)
```

Everything was great until I tried to get ***currencyCode***, ***currencySymbol***, ***currencyName***, ***languageCode***, ***languageName***

I tried a bunch of combinations of `NSLocale.objectForKey` and `NSLocale.displayNameForKey` and nothing worked.

Do you know how I can get a list of countries using ISOCountryCode with respective currency and language information ?

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and explain what values you get versus what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of the relevant keys and value types:

[NSLocale component keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSLocale_Component_Keys)

You use the function [`objectForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLocale/objectForKey:) to retrieve the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you check `currentLocale()` method, `localeIdentifier` is a string format like "en_CN". `ISOCountryCode()` method just return a list of country codes each is part of localeIdentifier. You may use NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers() instead.

```
let countriesIdentifiers = NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers()
for country in countriesIdentifiers {

let anyLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: country)
// code here .....
}
```